# No one of illegitimate birth shall enter the assembly of the Lord.... even to the 10th generation. Deut, 23:2 NASB. Really?

Tags: deuteronomy, legitimacy

Were not some of Jacob's sons illegitimate?

Comment: This question is devoid of detail and clarity. And empty of any research. Which sons are they to whom the question refers ?

Comment: Isn't Jacob lived before the law was given?

Comment: @NigelJ - Granted! More often than not, I will spend an inordinate amount of time researching for Q & A's, answers in particular, often getting too profound in the writings (even for myself), not to mention controversial, resulting in having little to no attention paid, so I decided to take a different tack this time and let others do the research. This Q came about from notes, to self, from over 30 years ago, after having forced myself to read the bible from front to back (something I was never won't to do), making notes to self as I went along. It took me less than 2 minutes to compose/copy.

Comment: @NigelJ - At the time of my note taking, I was thinking of those sons born to Jacob by the *maid servants* Bilhah and Zilpah, who in my mind were hardly legitimate.

Comment: @VincentWong - What you say was indeed so, but still.....

Comment: "the tenth generation" sounds a bit harsh, especially in light of the verse that states that the curse from the father's sins are going to be passed down to (only) the third generation. But, maybe the thousand generations blessings trump that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote two surrounding verses:

> Deut 23:1-3 - **1** “No one who is emasculated or has his male organ
> cut off may enter the assembly of the LORD. **2** No one of
> illegitimate birth may enter the assembly of the LORD; none of his
> descendants, even to the tenth generation, may enter the assembly of
> the LORD. **3** No Ammonite or Moabite may enter the assembly of the
> LORD; none of their descendants, even to the tenth generation, may
> ever enter the assembly of the LORD

There are so many counter-examples of this law in operation in Israel's history.

Before getting to these, let me expand upon the noun מַמְזֵר (mamzer) = " a bastard, child of incest" (BDB).  Strong's suggests "Born of a Jewish father and a heathen mother -- bastard." The Talmud explains the term homiletically as consisting of the words mum (defect) and zar (strange/alien), a euphemism for an illicit union in the person's lineage. (Yevamot 76b)

Examples:

- Judah and Tamar's twins **Perez and Zerah** became the parents of the tribe of Judah and human progenitors of Christ (Gen 38:27-30).  Thus, the boys be the product of a union that was both incestuous (his daughter-in-law) and illicit because it amounted to (as far as Judah was concerned) a contract for prostitution.
- **Boaz** was born of Salmon and Rahab the prostitute of Jericho (Matt 1:5)
- **Obed** was born of Boaz and Ruth, a Moabitess whose progeny, according to Deut 23:3, could not enter the congregation for at least 10 generations.  Yet his grandson was King David (Matt 1:5, 6)
- **Solomon** was the product of David's final wife, Bathsheba whose first son died.  However, none of this really legitimized David's marriage to Bathsheba which was extremely irregular and scandalous because of the incident with Uriah.
- Isa 56:3, 4 also records that God would make eunuch's legitimate people of God
- God reinforces this point in Isa 56:7 where He declares that the sanctuary (!!) would be a house of prayer for ALL nations, presumably, including Moab and Amalek in direct contradistinction to Deut 23:1-3.  Jesus even quotes this Isa 56:7 passage in Matt 21:13, Mark 11:17, Luke 19:46.
- Even Jesus Himself, was viewed by many contemporaries as illegitimate because of His irregular birth.

So, what are we to make of the Torah law in Deut 23:1-4?

Judging from the point of view of the NT and Matthew's genealogy (ch 1) it appears that God used this as a series of examples of divine grace - indeed, Matthew's genealogy appears to make this very point by deliberately quoting the several examples of irregular births.

Comment: I knew I could count on you. + 1.

Comment: Judah and Tamar - before the Torah was given; different rules. Rahab - converted to Judaism; her past isn't relevant. Ruth - since you're citing the Talmud, note that the same passage says the rule applies only to male Ammonites and Moabites, not females. Bathsheba - again, the Talmud in several places states that Uriah had legally divorced her, so that David's liaison with her was irregular but not actually adultery. Entering the Temple and being part of the Jewish people - the law in Deuteronomy isn't barring that, just marriage into the body of the Jewish people.

Comment: @Meir - interesting claims made to justify the Jewish heroes that are not supported by eny evidence.

Answer (score 4):

Jacob's sons were not illegitimate in the sense that Dt. 23:2 means, as they were born to women given to him by his wives as surrogate mothers. In fact the first reference to them in the bible describes them as "wife" not "concubine." (see below)

The term used in Dt. 23 is *mamzer* (Strong's 4464). This refers to a [child conceived in adultery by a married woman](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10341-mamzer).

> The mamzer, rendered "bastard" in the A. V., is something worse than
> an illegitimate child... issuing
> either from adultery between a married woman and a man other than her
> husband, or from incest.

The women in question had no husband, so they did not commit adultery, and their children were thus not *mamzers*. Indeed, the Bible never speaks disparaging of Bilhah and Zilpah. When they were given to Jacob, the word used for them is "wife."

Gen. 20 quotes Rachel:

> “Here is my maidservant Bilhah. Have intercourse with her, and let
> her give birth on my knees, so that I too may have children through
> her.” 4 So she gave him her maidservant Bilhah as wife, and Jacob had
> intercourse with her.

Genesis 30:9-10 says:

> When Leah saw that she had ceased to bear children, she took her
> maidservant Zilpah and gave her to Jacob as wife. So Leah’s maidservant Zilpah bore a son for Jacob.

Thus both of Jacob's concubines are also called "wife," and both of them acted as surrogate mothers, betrothed to Jacob by his primary wives because of their fertility problems. They were unmarried; he took public responsibility for them; and he broke no law in conceiving children with them at his other wives' request.

**Conclusion**: Whether Bilhah and Zilpah were wives or concubines, their sons were not *mamzers*,  because these women were provided to Jacob by his other wives as surrogate mothers, in order that he could have many sons. These were not legitimate marriages in the modern sense, but the sons produced by them  were not excluded under the provisions of Dt. 32.